# Ubuntu 11.10 broken after updates

Tags: updates

I have updated my Ubuntu 11.10 completely, I had been running it without updating without any issues, had installed quite a lot of packages, installed Nvidia drivers, media players, browsers, etc, and everything was just fine.

However, after yesterday update the system wont load Lightdm anymore. It just loads the purple Ubuntu screen and won't get past that point.

Certain services like OpenSSH and NetworkManager seem to work just fine, making the computer accessible from the net.

Computer specs are as follows:

- Processor: AMD 6000+ Dual Core 3.12Ghz
- Memory: 4GB ( 2x2GB DDR2 800Mhz on dual channel )
- Hard Drive: 320GB ( 150GB allocated to Ubuntu, the rest are just files )
- Version: Ubuntu 11.10 ( Oneiric Ocelot ) 64 bit
- Video Card: Nvidia GeForce 9600GT 512MB DDR3 using latest drivers from Nvidia.com

( starting this question as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103556/system-will-not-boot-after-applying-updates/106180#106180) appears to be a different issue )

Comment: try `dpkg --configure -a` or `apt-get install -f`

Comment: There were no broken packages, the output of these commands show no errors and the system still won't load Lightdm